# Understanding Struct Size Variations in C/C++: The Impact of Member Ordering and Data Alignment

Tags: c, struct, compiler-optimization, bit-fields

Why does the size of struct bit_man1 result in 8 bytes while struct bit_man2 results in 4 bytes, even though both structures contain the same types and amount of data? Consider the structures defined below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// packing is done in 4 bytes size since int is the biggest in struct
struct bit_man1 {
    int a:5;        //5 bits                                 
    int b:8;        //5+8 =13 bits
    char abc[2];    //2 bytes 8 +8 +13= 29  bit
    int z:2;       // 2 bits 29+2 =31
  
        
};

struct bit_man2 {
    int a:5;        //5 bits                                 
    int b:8;        //5+8 =13 bits
    int z:2;        // 2 bits 13+2=15
    char abc[2];    //2 bytes 8 +8 +15= 31  bit
  
        
};

int main() {
 
   
    printf("Size of bit_man1: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(struct bit_man1));
    printf("Size of bit_man2: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(struct bit_man2));
    return 0;
}
```

gcc version

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

But we get an ouput like so

```
Size of bit_man1: 8 bytes
Size of bit_man2: 4 bytes
```

as packing prioritizes 4 bytes should'nt the int z:2 (2 bits) be packed into the 29 bits resulting in 31 bits, is there a any reason why the compiler allocates another 4 bytes??

Comment: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member?rq=1)

Comment: Also, bitfields make it even worse. They are very implementation-specific.

Comment: And a field such as `char abc[2];` will never be combined into any bitfield.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i did go thorough the post, you linked before posting this, if you force it to pack using `__attribute__((__packed__));` ` bit_man1` will yield 5 bytes and `bit_man2` will yield 4 bytes, best i can think of on whats happening is due to the boundary.

Comment: `struct bit_man1` could *never* be less than 5 bytes.

Comment: Thats exactly what i said...... `struct bit_man1` will be 5 and `struct bit_man2` is 4 bytes respectively

Comment: Using GCC on my Linux system, `offsetof(struct bit_man1, abc)` and `offsetof(struct bit_man2, abc)` were both `2`, and `_Alignof(struct bit_man1)` and `_Alignof(struct bit_man2)` were both `4`. So that's why `sizeof(struct bit_man1)` is `8`. The only question is why the compiler decided to set the alignment to `4`? EDIT: It will be determined by the ABI.

Answer (score 1):

Adjacent bitfields can be grouped together into the same allocation unit, but bitfields and non-bitfields are not.  This means that the `abc` member will take up 2 complete bytes and not occupy any partial bytes such as unused bit in a unit containing a bitfield.

In the first case, you start with two bitfields totaling 13 bits.  These fit into a single 2 byte allocation unit.  The `char` array occupies the next 2  complete bytes.  Then the remaining bitfield takes up another byte.  Then since the base type of the bitfields is `int` the struct is padded out another 3 bytes (assuming an `int` takes up 4 bytes) for a total of 8.

In the second case you start with three bitfields totaling 15 bits.  These fit into a single 2 byte allocation unit as in the prior case.  The `char` array occupies the next 2 complete bytes for a total of 4 bytes used.

Comment: "Then since the base type of the bitfields is int the struct is padded out another 3 bytes (assuming an int takes up 4 bytes) for a total of 8.". That's basically up to the whims of the compiler. There should not be anything special about the last member of the structure being a bit-field member.

Comment: I would like to follow up on
""Adjacent bitfields can be grouped together into the same allocation unit, but bitfields and non-bitfields are not. This means that the abc member will take up 2 complete bytes and not occupy any partial bytes"" 
If the above is to be true, this below struct should yield (5+(27 pad))+((8+8)+16 pad)+(5+(27 pad)) = 12 bytes
```struct bit_man1 {   
int a:5;  //5 bits                                  
char abc[2]; //2 bytes 8 +8 = 16 +5 =21 bits
int az:5;   // 5 bits 21+5 = 26 bits   // 6 bits paddded 
}; // over all size will be 4 bytes as observed not 12
```

Comment: @RakshithBS The first bitfield occupies 1 byte, the array occupies 2 bytes, and the second bitfield occupies 1 byte.  Total is 4 bytes.

Comment: The bit-field base type seems to control the alignment in GCC, and the maximum size of the allocation unit, but not the actual size of the allocation unit. So a bit-field base type of `int` causes the struct type to be aligned at least as strictly as `int` (which is 4 on my system). E.g., changing the base type to `short` (16-bit) changes the overall alignment of the struct type from 4 to 2 on my system, making the sizeof `struct bit_man1` with `short` bit-fields 6 bytes on my system.

Comment: … For example on my system, adding an extra bit-field member `int c:4;` as follows: `struct bit_man1 { int a: 5; int b: 8; int c:4; char abc[2]; int z:2;}` has a size of 8, an alignment of 4, and the `abc` member is at offset 3, so the actual size of the first allocation unit appears to be 3 bytes. (My system is little-endian with bit-fields allocated from the l.s.b., so `a` occupies byte 0 bits 0 to 4, `b` occupies byte 0 bits 5 to 7 & byte 1 bits 0 to 4, `c` occupies byte 1 bits 5 to 7 & byte 2 bit 0, `abc` occupies bytes 3 to 4, `z` occupies byte 4 bits 0 to 1, & bytes 5 to 7 are padding.)